# Flexbox does not work in header alignment

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to have the contents of the header justified as space-between to send one to the left and one to the right.

```css
body {
min-height: 960px;
background-color: #222; 
}
header {
min-height: 250px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
#hero {
color: white;
font-size: 155px;
font-family: 'Elsie' cursive;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: column;
align-items: center;
}
#logo {
height: 36px;
width: 67px;

}

.headline::before {
content: "design";
opacity: 0;
animation-name: animate;
animation-duration: 4s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-delay: 0.5s;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes animate {
11.1% {content:"design"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(0);}
22.2% {content: "design"; opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);}
33.3% {content:"design"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px);}
44.4% {content: "build"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(0);}
55.5% {content:"build"; opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);}
66.6% {content: "build"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px);}
77.7% {content: "innovate"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(0);}
88.8% {content: "innovate"; opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);}
99.9%{content: "innovate"; opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px);}
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo-8.png" alt="">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<section id="hero">
    <div id="lets_wrapper">
        <h1 id="lets">let's</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 class="headline"></h1>
    </div>    
    <div id="together_wrapper">
        <p>together</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

I also tried setting height and width to the children elements but that doesn't seem to work, the logo and the text keep stacking one on top of the other in the top-left corner. There is also another section tag just below that that has a flexbox attribute displaying flex, wrap, column and align-items center.
What am I doing wrong?
Later edit: I have added all the code I have right now as I think maybe something is conflicting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I thinnk your code is working fine.

```css
header {
  min-height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img id="logo" src="images/logo-8.png" alt="This is Logo">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Work</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Bit of trial and error here but what happens if you put the flex and space-between commands onto the Nav CSS rather than the Header CSS?

Comment: Nothing changes. And wouldn't that only justify the contents of the nav rather than the nav itself and the image?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem inside my `reset.css` file as I loaded it after my `style.css` and it set the header to display: `block`. Noob mistake, sorry :))